# How to run X server on other Computer/other Monitor?

Tags: xorg

I have two laptop, and one external monitor, LCD.
Firstly, I want my primary display to run in runlevel 2 (TTY), and my external monitor to run on runlevel 3 (Xserver). We can't do this I presume? I conclude it after searching in this forum.

If it is, can I work still in runlevel 2, but if I do need an X display, I would output it into my another laptop... is't possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom `xorg.conf`

edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/X11/xorg.conf

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

`xorg.conf` is divided into sections, and you only need a few sections.

You may not need more then a Monitor section

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    Option         "Enable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    Option         "Enable" "true"
EndSection
```

If you need more then that ...

```
Section Screen
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen         "Screen0"
EndSection
```

In terms of run levels, Ubuntu uses Upstart, and to some extent the idea of runlevels is depreciated. You will need to edit your Upstart scripts so that X does not start in runlevel 2 and append "2" or "3" to your grub linux (kernel) line.

Upstart is not *too* bad to learn, see [Upstart How To](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto) to get started.

That should get you started, post back if you get stuck.